# Stop jQuery chaining in an elegant way

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I'm a bit confused that I can't find the answer at once on SO. The question is about the codestyle.

Consider an example:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('click', doSomething);
```

What happens if there are no inputs on the page? The result of this selector appears to be `null` and we get an error.

So, we have to make the code bigger and uglier:

```
var inputs = $('input[type=text]');

if (inputs) {
    inputs.on('click', doSomething);
}
```

I love jQuery and am expecting a more elegant and short form of this solution.

---

**UPDATE**

The reason of this problem was `prototype.js` included by the 3-party script on a page. Apologises, I should have tested the problem in a sandbox before posting on SO

Comment: No, this is exactly what does *not* happen. You can write `$("foobarbaz").on('click', whatever)` and it will always work (and do nothing of course).

Comment: Try it, before following your logic!

Comment: The reason was that the jQuery `$` object got owerwritten. Apologises. I think we should delete this question. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Dan did you have another library included? A full solution might be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Yep, prototype was included by some 3-party script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a jQuery selector will always return a jQuery  object, you will never get null.

```
$('#Not exist!').attr('foo', 'foo'); //no error, returns jQuery
```

unlike `document.getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('Not exist!') == null
```

Comment: @Dan, I bet it will not... waiting.

Comment: btw this is the single biggest reason why i prefer jquery to mootools. no random null element error in the middle of a chain. very graceful use of chaining and null handling..

Comment: I updated the fiddle from my answer to use 1.7.2, and the result is the same - jQuery selectors always return a jQuery object (with a count of zero if no elements were matched). http://jsfiddle.net/YFcjy/2/

Comment: The reason was that the jQuery `$` object was owerwritten.

Comment: It was prototype.js. I know that YIU causes the same errors. And jQuery is really great

Answer (score 2):

The selector actually does not return `null` if it doesn't find a match and this is intentional, so that chaining does not break. This is in line with jQuery's "write less, do more" motto.

I made a [jsFiddle to illustrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/YFcjy/1/). Open up the developer tools on your browser and look at the console.

```
var doSomething = function(){};
$('input[type=text]').on('click', doSomething); //No error

//...because this:

var obj = $('input[type=text]'); //is a jQuery object, even 
                                 //though there are no <input> elements

console.dir(obj); //Inspect the console. you get: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]
```

I hope that makes sense. You can simply do the former in your example:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('click', doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no error, just an empty object. you can go with

```
$('input[type=text]').on('click', doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works...

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('click', doSomething);
```

Comment: Well, both `text` and `"text"` variants work fine and exactly in the same way either in CSS2+ or jQuery 1+. The problem was that at some point of time the `$` variable got overwritten by `prototype.js` :P, which is not so great as jQuery!